# How to change value of a number input field when using a different Culture - Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, globalization

In my application we're letting the user change language (culture) freely. But some cultures changes the "." to a "," in the decimal displays.

The problem is that the value isn't shown if the culture is changed from en-US. I guess the input value should have a decmial number with the format of xx.xxx. But even if I change the format to have a dot instead of a comma in it. it still doesn't show any value.

Basicly 
When a culture is set to sv-SE the input field can't show any numbers.

```
@using System.Globalization;

<input type="number"
       step="@Step"
       value="@Value" 
       @onchange="(args) => InputHandler((string)args.Value)"/>

@code
{
    string Step = "0.01";
    decimal Value = 1.05m;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("sv-SE");
        //CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
    }

    private void InputHandler(string value) {
        var decimalValue = decimal.Parse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Value = decimalValue;
    }
}
```

Edit:

So what I'm ended up doing is a horribly bodge. In the real application I'm having the value as an input parameter. So I added the set param hook and changed the decimal value into a string which I manipulate (change commas into dots, and replace the minus sign with a new one).

It does work, but it looks horrendous. So if you have any idea how to do it differently. Please let me know.

```
public override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
{
    var value = parameters.GetValueOrDefault<decimal?>("Value");
    valueAsString = value.ToString().Replace(",", "."); 

    if (value < 0)
    {
        valueAsString = "-" + valueAsString.Substring(1, valueAsString.Length - 1);
    }
    return base.SetParametersAsync(parameters);
}
```